# Can i change title of my toolbar in my constructor if yes then how can it possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment, android-studio-2.0

Can i change title of my toolbar in my constructor if yes then how can it possible?

```
public DashboardFragment() {


((AppCompatActivity) this.getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("DashBoard");
}
```

Comment: You should change title in onCreate() or after it

Comment: But i want to change in constructor according to my code.

Comment: If your fragment is embed in xml layout, the constructor will run before activity inited, then your will get an null pointer exception.

Comment: The call to getActivity() may return null if the Fragment isn't attached yet. So calling getActivity in the constructor will not work. You should call it when you know the Fragment is attached to the Activity, such as in onCreate.

Comment: i know that's why i"m asking for some other method to change my title,......

Comment: Or you can add the fragment into fragment manager instead of embed in xml layout

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: i tried this also but this isn't working.

Comment: Why you need to change the title in fragment's constructor? You can do it in fragment's onCreate() or onAttach() method, this two methods will run after activity inited.

Comment: I have six items in my navigation drawer and i want to set my title according to my selected fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Toolbar defined in your Activity's xml, you can access it from a Fragment using the following method:

Override the `onAttach()` method in your Fragment to get a reference to the parent Activity once it is available. Then, simply get your reference to the Toolbar (that should be defined in your Activity xml) and simply set the title. Like this...

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Your Custom Title");
}
```